# Diretório ./demoCA não existe no openssl windows

Tags: certificado-digital, ssl, openssl

Olá,

Estou tentando gerar um certificado pelo openssl do windows e me deparei com vários erros envolvendo o diretório ./demoCA. 
No arquivo openssl.cnf

dir     = ./demoCA

Baixei várias versões do openssl no formato zip mas em nenhuma delas tem um diretório chamado demoCA, o que eu faço? preciso criar manualmente esse diretório?